# getting the list of changed files in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, akamai

We have html/angular project on Git and is deployed to the web server using the Jenkins.

The web server is behind Akamai CDN cache and the web contents are cached and served. I need to clear the cache of the updated files after the build completed.

I can clear the complete cache but that will take significant time. If I have the modified file list from the last successful build I can construct the URL and clear the cache for it.

Any help is appropriated

Comment: What code have you tried so far? I'm sure you've figured out at least parts of the solution, e.g. what the call to the Akamai API is, or how to find changed files.

Comment: It also depends very much on how those files get changed. Only in Git or in the generated artifacts?

Comment: @StephenKing: yeah. we already have scripts created to call akamai refresh given a URL. We can call full refresh but that will take time and increase the server load as everything in the cache will be purged. I just need to find a way to get the list of file changed. then based on the path, I can generate the URL to clear.

Comment: @StephenKing: files are only changed in Git. there are angular HTML pages. app changes are deployed superlatively from a different git repo.

Comment: So this is absolutely not related to Akamai...